# How to substitute actual type arguments in a generic method to obtain final types of its value arguments?

Tags: scala, generics, scala-macros

I have a macro with a signature like

```
def generateSomething[A] = macro ...
```

That is, it accepts a type parameter. The type is expected to be a case class and so it always has corresponding `apply` method in its companion object.

This macro, among everything else, generates an invocation of this `apply` method, so, for example, for this class:

```
case class A(x: Int, y: String)
```

the following call will be generated:

```
A.apply(someFunction[Int], someFunction[String])
```

I extract parameter types for `someFunction` calls from `apply` signature.

Everything is fine unless `A` is parameterized:

```
case class A[T](x: Int, y: T)
```

With my current approach the following is generated for `generateSomething[A[String]]`:

```
A.apply[String](someFunction[Int], someFunction[T])
```

which is obviously not valid.

However, I don't know how to obtain `apply`'s argument after all of its type parameters are known. That is, I don't know how to make sure that

```
generateSomething[A[String]]
```

generates

```
A.apply[String](someFunction[Int], someFunction[String])
```

and not the piece above. Is it possible?

**Update**

I think I should reformulate the question.

Suppose there is a class

```
case class A[T1, ..., Tn](x1: A1, ..., xm: Am)
```

where `Ai` can depend on arbitrary subset of `Tk`. Examples:

```
// T1 = T
// A1 = Int, A2 = T
case class B[T](x: Int, y: T)

// T1 = U, T2 = V
// A1 = Map[U, V], A2 = List[V]
case class C[U, V](m: Map[U, V], l: List[V])

// T1 = W
// A1 = W, A2 = W
case class D[W](t: W, u: W)

// No Ts
// A1 = String, A2 = Double
case class E(v: String, w: Double)  // no type parameters at all
```

I need to write a macro which accepts a type argument `A` and expands to `A.apply` method call with preprocessed arguments:

```
myMacro[A[U1, ..., Un]]

// expands to

A.apply[U1, ..., Un](preprocess[A1], ..., preprocess[An])
```

`Uk` here are actual type arguments which are substituted instead of `Tk`. For example (using classes above):

```
myMacro[B[String]] -> B.apply[String](preprocess[Int], preprocess[String])

myMacro[C[Int, Double]] -> C.apply[Int, Double](preprocess[Map[Int, Double]], preprocess[List[Double]])

myMacro[D[Long]] -> D.apply[Long](preprocess[Long], preprocess[Long])

myMacro[E] -> D.apply(preprocess[String], preprocess[Double])
```

You see, `apply` argument types can depend on type parameters. While these parameters are known to the macro (because it is always invoked with concrete types), I don't know how to "pass" these parameters "through" to `apply` function in order for `preprocess` type arguments to be correct.

**Update 2**

[Here](https://gist.github.com/netvl/d04632c3101b6632f0c9) is loosely what I currently have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
case class X[A](a: A)

object TParamMacro {
  import scala.language.experimental.macros
  import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.Context

  def m[A](): A = macro mImpl[A]

  def mImpl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)(): c.Expr[A] = {
    import c.universe._
    val TypeRef(pre, sym, args) = weakTypeTag[A].tpe
    val t = args.head
    val expr = 
      if (t <:< typeOf[String]) q"""X.apply[$t]("hi")"""
      else if (t <:< typeOf[Int]) q"X.apply[$t](42)"
      else q"X.apply[$t](null)"
    c.Expr[A](expr)
  }
}

object Test extends App {
  Console println TParamMacro.m[X[String]]()
}
```

More example:

```
object TParamMacro {
  import scala.language.experimental.macros
  import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.Context

  def m[A](): Any = macro mImpl[A]

  def mImpl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)() = {
    import c.universe._
    val TypeRef(pre, sym, args) = weakTypeTag[A].tpe
    val t = args.head
    val expr = if (t <:< typeOf[String]) q"""X.apply[List[$t]](List.apply[$t]("hi"))"""
      else if (t <:< typeOf[Int]) q"X.apply[List[$t]](List.apply[$t](42))"
      else q"X.apply[List[$t]](Nil)"
    expr
  }
}
```

Where

```
Console println TParamMacro.m[X[String]]()
```

yields

```
X(List(hi))
```

Edit with the gist repaired:

```
package evaluator

import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox.Context

object Evaluator {
  def preprocess[T]: T = ???

  def evaluate[A]: Any = macro evaluateImpl[A]

  def evaluateImpl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context): c.Expr[A] = {
    import c.universe._

    val tpe = weakTypeOf[A]
    val sym = tpe.typeSymbol.asClass

    require(sym.isCaseClass)

    val companionSym = sym.companion
    val companionTpe = companionSym.typeSignature
    val applyMethod = companionTpe.member(TermName("apply")).asMethod

    val paramTypes = applyMethod.paramLists.flatten.map(_.typeSignature)
    Console println s"apply($paramTypes)"

    val TypeRef(_, _, tpeTypeArgs) = tpe

    val from = applyMethod.typeParams
    val to   = tpeTypeArgs
    val arguments = paramTypes map { t =>
      val u = if (from.nonEmpty) t.substituteTypes(from, to) else t
      Console println s"param is $t, subst is $u"
      q"evaluator.Evaluator.preprocess[$u]"
    }

    c.Expr(q"$companionSym.apply[..$tpeTypeArgs](..$arguments)")
  }
}
```

So you're just substituting your "actual type args" for the method's type parameters. It's useful to use "parameter" for the formal parameter and "argument" for the actual arg in an application.

Sample:

```
package evaluator

case class A(x: Int, y: String)

case class B[T](x: Int, y: T)

case class C[U, T](x: Int, y: T, z: U)

object Test extends App {
  Evaluator.evaluate[A]
  Evaluator.evaluate[B[String]]
  Evaluator.evaluate[C[String, List[Int]]]
}
```

Using

```
-Xprint:typer
```

then

```
A.apply(evaluator.Evaluator.preprocess[Int], evaluator.Evaluator.preprocess[String]);
B.apply[String](evaluator.Evaluator.preprocess[Int], evaluator.Evaluator.preprocess[String]);
C.apply[String, List[Int]](evaluator.Evaluator.preprocess[Int], evaluator.Evaluator.preprocess[List[Int]], evaluator.Evaluator.preprocess[String])
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how it could help. Please see my update. I need a general mechanism for handling case classes with arbitrary type parameters and arbitrary number of value arguments.

Comment: The `$t` is the type arg, shown in a quasiquoted application. You can use the list of args anyway you want. In your edit, substitute `List.apply` for `preprocess` and that's the example I gave. Or, show us what you tried and we'll tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: Your program works specifically for type `X` which has single type parameter and single value parameter. I need to work with types with arbitrary number of types and type parameters. Ok, I'll provide my code shortly.

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/netvl/d04632c3101b6632f0c9) is what I currently have. You can see how it works for concrete types like `case class A(x: Int, y: String)` and for generic types like `case class B[T](x: Int, y: T)`.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I *knew* it has something to do with `substituteTypes`, but I tried it backwards - I invoked `substituteTypes` on the method type itself to obtain its final signature, and it didn't work. It didn't even occur to me to try using `substituteTypes` on each type argument separately. It does works as I wanted, thank you very much for your patience!

Comment: I think it's tricky because the API namespace is so flat. People who do this stuff every day might think it's easy. I can't see the trees for the trees, as they say.

Answer (score -1):

The [Scala macro docs](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/bundles.html) provide some insight:

```
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context

class Impl(val c: Context) {
  def mono = c.literalUnit
  def poly[T: c.WeakTypeTag] = c.literal(c.weakTypeOf[T].toString)
}

object Macros {
  def mono = macro Impl.mono
  def poly[T] = macro Impl.poly[T]
}
```

The `poly` method above calls `c.weakTypeOf` which captures the erased type information by creating an implicit at compile time. A similar pattern can likely aid in reifying your macro.

EDIT for update above:

The `c.WeakTypeTag` captures type information at the invocation site. The compiler, in a need to fulfill the type bounds we apply to the macro arguments, applies an implicit conversion which captures this info from your types.

The idea was that once you have this info, you can use it to get a string for the unknown type, which you can use during reification.

As far as the variance in the number of type parameters is concerned, I think the number of parameters to the macro has to be independent of the type it's being applied to to make any sense, i.e per your last block I would instead do something like this (assuming they all had two fields to `apply`):

```
myMacro[B, Int, String]] -> B.apply(preprocess[Int], preprocess[String])

myMacro[C, Map[Int,Double], List[Double]] -> C.apply(preprocess[Map[Int, Double]], preprocess[List[Double]])

myMacro[D, Long, Long] -> D.apply(preprocess[Long], preprocess[Long])

myMacro[E, String, Double] -> E.apply(preprocess[String], preprocess[Double])
```

Again, since this is pseudo-code your mileage may vary, but applying some uniformity to your macro's signature (and perhaps apply implementations) will probably help your implementation greatly.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how this could help. Please read my update.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but unfortunately I'm not sure I understand what you mean. `myMacro` should work with arbitrary types with arbitrary type parameters, and it has single parameter. The number of `apply` arguments does not and can not depend on the number of type parameters of the original type either.

Comment: You will likely need to implement macros for each arity you want to support I reckon. It will be a lot of work.

Comment: I can't do this because the macro in question is a materializer of serializers for types unknown in advance. Moreover, the companion object of the type can have arbitrary `apply` method, so there is no information about `apply` argument types at the call site. And I'm still not convinced it would help to link `apply` type arguments with its argument types.

Comment: You should look at the shapeless library, the [`Generic`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#generic-representation-of-sealed-families-of-case-classes) type from that library basically turns class instances into a form of list, which you can apply [polymorphic methods](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#polymorphic-function-values) to. Then you can convert back to the original type. See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4470f54f53f7c14cfc9e) for an example.